# Wordpress default template for taxonomy name

Tags: wordpress

i have been testing taxonomies. i use to handle my taxonomy files with either taxonomy.php or taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php or with taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php. For example:

> localhost/cars/i20/
>   where 'cars' is taxonomy and 'i20' is the term. and i made it handle with taxonomy-cars.php with desired results.

but i am having difficulties trying to get a default template for taxonomy-name. For example:

> localhost/cars/
>   in this case, index.php is handling this url, not by the taxonomy.php file. 
>   Anyone knows what template/file handles this ?

Answer (score 1):

See the  [Template Hiearchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for a more detailed break down of how WordPress chooses the template.

**OR**

This Stack Exchange Meta would help you [click here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61896/how-to-create-a-custom-template-for-a-custom-taxonomy)

Comment: is you're facing any error, if yes then which one? or getting problem with permalink? or you can tell difficulty whom you're talking about?

Comment: its not the permalink. the index.php (i am not using 404.php right now) is always handling the link.

Answer (score 0):

U can use **taxonomy-cars.php** and put your code hear

Template structure mange by 2 files which file call first priority and generate [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy):

***Source File***

> The template hierarchy functions are located in
>   **wp-includes/template.php.**
>
> The template-load hierarchy is located in
>   **wp-includes/template-loader.php.**

[template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/template.php#L0)

[template-loader.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L0)

```
if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES ) :
            $template = false;
            if     ( is_404()            && $template = get_404_template()            ) :
            elseif ( is_search()         && $template = get_search_template()         ) :
            elseif ( is_front_page()     && $template = get_front_page_template()     ) :
            elseif ( is_home()           && $template = get_home_template()           ) :
            elseif ( is_post_type_archive() && $template = get_post_type_archive_template() ) :
            elseif ( is_tax()            && $template = get_taxonomy_template()       ) :
            elseif ( is_attachment()     && $template = get_attachment_template()     ) :
                    remove_filter('the_content', 'prepend_attachment');
            elseif ( is_single()         && $template = get_single_template()         ) :
            elseif ( is_page()           && $template = get_page_template()           ) :
            elseif ( is_category()       && $template = get_category_template()       ) :
            elseif ( is_tag()            && $template = get_tag_template()            ) :
            elseif ( is_author()         && $template = get_author_template()         ) :
            elseif ( is_date()           && $template = get_date_template()           ) :
            elseif ( is_archive()        && $template = get_archive_template()        ) :
            elseif ( is_comments_popup() && $template = get_comments_popup_template() ) :
            elseif ( is_paged()          && $template = get_paged_template()          ) :
            else :
                    $template = get_index_template();
            endif;
            /**
             * Filter the path of the current template before including it.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             *
             * @param string $template The path of the template to include.
             */
            if ( $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template ) )
                    include( $template );
            return;
    endif;
```

[image]

Comment: in my case, taxonomy-cars.php is not handling the url. this file is already here in my folder.